# Write and read data from Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, svelte

I have the following small setup in Svelte:

[image: Calendar and check boxes]

Calendar and checkboxes work. What I am trying to understand is the best way to read and store the option responses for each date that is selected by the user.

Here is what I currently have in my svelte file:

```js
<script>
    import Datepicker from "praecox-datepicker";
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let name;

    let day;
    let questions = [
            {value: "Condition 1", checked: false},
            {value: "Condition 2", checked: false},
            {value: "Condition 3", checked: false},
            {value: "Condition 4", checked: false}
        ];
    let selectedQuestions = [];

    $:  questions = {...questions,
        [day]: [
            {value: "Condition 1", checked: false},
            {value: "Condition 2", checked: false},
            {value: "Condition 3", checked: false},
            {value: "Condition 4", checked: false},
    ]
    };


    $: {
        selectedQuestions = questions.savedValues[day]
};

    $: selectedQuestions = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(questions).filter(([key, value]) => key == day))

    $: day = day;
    $: readDate = new Date(day);
    $: mm = readDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {month: "long"});
    $: dd = readDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {day: "numeric"});
    $: yyyy = readDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {year: "numeric"});

    onMount(async () => {
        day = new Date()
    });
</script>

<main>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <Datepicker pickerRule='singleChoice' bind:pickerResult={day}/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <p>{mm} {dd}, {yyyy}</p>
            <ul>
                {#each questions as question}
                <li>
                    <input type=checkbox checked={question.checked}>
                    {question.value}
                </li>
                {/each}

            </ul>
            </div>
</main>
```

The current issue is I'm not sure how to access the filtered object and if I'm even accessing that properly.

To recap the workflow would need to handle the following:

1. User loads page, options are presented and default to false.
2. User selects options for first date, these are saved, and user moves to new day.
3. New list of checkboxes are presented, all default to false. User updates options and these are saved.
4. User revisits item and updates previously input information.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/group-inputs

Comment: Could you please provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-svelte)?

Comment: @johannchopin For some reason, Svelte and NPM packages don't play nice together on codesandbox. I tried throwing one together before making the post but couldn't get the calendar working properly.

Comment: @Hayden the calendar works in the REPL

Comment: @JHeth thanks but the REPL does not have a way for me to share, unless I'm totally missing something.

Comment: As long as you have a Github account you can fork, save, share direct links, look at your saved projects. Just login with Github by clicking the button shown [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/WXpYnsXQsw). After you have a saved project you can just grab the URL and share it.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1.Upgrade `praecox-datepicker` to version 1.0 or higher.

2.Use `bind:selected` to get the selected result.

3.Pass the selection result (start date) to the `viewDate` property to keep the view synchronized.

4.If you want a timely response, please submit an issue directly on Github.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f153bee994974251b59041832a099427?version=3.29.0)

[See more.](https://github.com/TIOvOIT/praecox-datepicker)